# Diverging integral

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, convergence-divergence, proof-explanation

I came accross this integral in my lecture notes:
$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x\log^n(x)} \,dx$

One of my classmates said that it converges for some values of $n$, but I don't see why...

How do I prove that it diverges for all values of $n$?

Answer (score 0):

In the case $n=0$, we readily know this not to be true, because $\lim_{x\to \infty }\log(x) = \infty$. So assume $n\neq 0$.

Let $u = \log(x)$, then $\frac{1}{x} dx = du$. The limits are $u=0$ to $u=\infty$.

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x[\log(x)]^n} dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{u^n} du = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{u^n}du + \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{u^{n}} du$$
Which evaluates to
$$\frac{1}{1-n} \left[\frac{1}{u^{n-1}}\right]_0^1 + \frac{1}{1-n} \left[\frac{1}{u^{n-1}}\right]_1^\infty$$
Now let us consider the first term
$$\frac{1}{1-n} \left[\frac{1}{u^{n-1}}\right]_0^1 = \frac{1}{1-n} \left[1 - \lim_{u\to 0} \frac{1}{u^{n-1}}\right]$$
This is finite, if and only if $n<1$. So suppose it is. But now, consider the second term
$$\frac{1}{1-n} \left[\frac{1}{u^{n-1}}\right]_1^\infty = \frac{1}{n-1}\left[\lim_{u\to \infty}\frac{1}{u^{n-1}} - 1\right] = \infty$$
because $n<1$ and so $\frac{1}{u^{n-1}}$ is some positive power of $u$ thus, $\lim_{u \to \infty}\frac{1}{u^{n-1}} = \infty$.